# How to get the input box value not the selected li tag on autocomplete by material ui?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How to get the value of inputbox on the autocomplete? Because if I used the e.target or e.currentTarget using onchange it will display the li tag not the inputbox.

**Inputbox**

[image]

**Console output**

[image]

```
Code
const handleChangeAutoComplete = (e, val) => {
    console.log(e.target);
  };


<Autocomplete
                  className={taskClasses.SelectAssignee}
                  options={users}
                  value={users.fullname}
                  onChange={handleChangeAutoComplete}
                  getOptionLabel={(user) => user.fullname}
                  renderInput={(params) => (
                    <TextField
                      placeholder='Assignee'
                      value={params.fullname}
                      {...params}
                      variant='outlined'
                    />
                  )}
                />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
onInputChange= {(event, value)=>{
  console.log(event)
  console.log(value)
}}
```

Comment: I also tried that but i need to get the value of the inputbox not the li tag of the selected value

Answer (score 1):

You will get user input in userInput state,You should get `val` second argument that you have passed to get object of selected value and instead of using onChange which listens for user select change , you need to use onInputChange , it will send what user types

```
const handleChangeAutoComplete = (e, val) => {
    console.log(val,"your value will be stored here inside second argument");
  };
```

Complete Code on how to handle autocomplete

```
/* eslint-disable no-use-before-define */
/* eslint-disable no-use-before-define */
import React, { useState } from "react";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import Autocomplete from "@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete";

export default function ComboBox() {
  const [userInput, setUserInput] = useState("");
  const [option, setOption] = useState("");
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      id="combo-box-demo"
      options={top10Films}
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
      style={{ width: 300 }}
      value={option}
      onChange={(e, v) => {
        setOption(v);
      }}
      onInputChange={(e, v) => {
        setUserInput(v);
      }}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField {...params} label="Combo box" variant="outlined" />
      )}
    />
  );
}

// Top 100 films as rated by IMDb users. http://www.imdb.com/chart/top
const top10Films = [
  { title: "The Shawshank Redemption", year: 1994 },
  { title: "The Godfather", year: 1972 },
  { title: "The Godfather: Part II", year: 1974 },
  { title: "The Dark Knight", year: 2008 },
  { title: "12 Angry Men", year: 1957 },
  { title: "Schindler's List", year: 1993 },
  { title: "Pulp Fiction", year: 1994 },
  { title: "The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King", year: 2003 },
  { title: "The Good, the Bad and the Ugly", year: 1966 },
  { title: "Fight Club", year: 1999 }
];
```

You can refer to this sandbox

[image: Edit Material demo (forked)]

Comment: I posted the result of the e.target and the result is the li tag is being the target not the inputbox that i want. See the image that i posted above

Comment: yeah got it check the second argument , of handleChangeAutoComplete it will pass the object value

Comment: I also tried that approach but the problem is I got two autocomplete and I will store the data into my useState and the problem is i can't use the spread operator on inline onchange

Comment: for value you need to pass the whole object to value , refer to the codesandbox , if you have two autocomplete then what you need to achieve needs to be explained in question